# Can multiple SELECT FOR UPDATES in a single transaction cause a race condition (Postgres)?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.1. I'm wondering if using multiple SELECT FOR UPDATES in the same transaction could potentially cause a race condition.

2 concurrent transactions:

> transaction 1: select for update on table 1 -- successfully acquires lock
>
> transaction 2: select for update on table 2 -- successfully acquires lock
>
> transaction 2: select for update on table 1 -- waiting for lock release from transaction 1
>
> transaction 1: select for update on table 2 -- waiting for lock release from transaction 2

What happens in this situation? Does one of the waiting transactions eventually time out? If so, is there a way to configure the timeout duration?

edit: is deadlock_timeout the configuration I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should look for the [`deadlock_timeout` in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-DEADLOCK-TIMEOUT).

But your scenario doesn't means that there *will be* a deadlock, 'cos PostgreSQL is using row-level locks and it is not clear whether your transactions are concurring for the same rows.

Another option is to use serialization level higher then [default `READ COMMITTED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html). But in this case your application should be ready to receive exceptions with [`SQLCODE=40001`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html):

```
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

This is expected, you should just re-try transaction as is.

A very good overview of Serializable isolation level you can [find on the wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI).

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL will detect the deadlock on step 4 and will fail the transaction. Here's what happened when I tried it in `psql` (only showing step 4):

```
template1=# SELECT * FROM table2 FOR UPDATE;
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 17536 waits for ShareLock on transaction 166946; blocked by process 18880.
Process 18880 waits for ShareLock on transaction 166944; blocked by process 17536.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
template1=#
```

This happens after 1s, which is the default timeout. The other answer has more information about this.