# can we select and update to database together?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have logic which selects some rows from the database that have a status of “Ready”
once I get the result set i need to update the status to 'processing' so no other thread can access these rows. then i have to perform some logic on the records in the result set and one the processing is complete i need to again update the record status to completed.

Questions:
is there a way in which when i execute the select statement - at that time only i can simultaneously change the status of the rows returned in result set.

can someone suggest if there a good way of implementing it in java.

Comment: That would be a database feature, not for programming language. Still, you can make a function in Java (or other PL) that handle both `UPDATE` and `SELECT` statements to solve your problem.

Comment: Another solution might be creating a stored procedure that does both `UPDATE` and `SELECT` statements, then execute the procedure using a `CallableStatement` in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are looking to do, but PostgreSQL also has `SELECT FOR UPDATE` functionality which will select rows and create an access lock on them: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` in a transaction the rows you want to process before updating them. `SELECT ... FOR SHARE NOWAIT` will fail with error if someone is updating selected rows or someone already done `SELECT ... FOR SHARE NOWAIT` on them.

Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE).

Answer (score 2):

Answering your main question: Yes, you can do that!

1. As others have mentioned, [`SELECT … FOR UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) is one of your options.
2. Another one is to increase serialization level. Please, have a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914195/can-multiple-select-for-updates-in-a-single-transaction-cause-a-race-condition/14914456#14914456) and follow the links there.

   It is worth mentioning, that going to up to [`REPEATABLE READ`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) or even `SERIALIZABLE` transactions will require changes on the Application side, as these isolation levels assume that some amount of transactions will be rolled back with serialization errors, which is a normal and expected behavior.

   Also, more strict isolation level (as well as more `SELECT … FOR UPDATE` queries) will cause performance drop and, possibly, may lead to the race conditions, depending on the design.
3. Please, have look at [this article on depesz.com](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/), it does a good overview of possible drawbacks in the related area.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for "locks" which allow you to lock a table/row (for yourself). A great example can be found on the PostgreSQL website:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html

Using locks will make sure that only you have access to the table/row and others won't untill you are done.

Comment: Locking the whole table may be a bad idea. Row level locks in this case are better.